# how load html file from asset directory in Browser android

Tags: android

I want a Html file in the folder ASSENT is in my view the phone browser.
I am use code:

```
 Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",       Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/Project17.html"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

but error
Please advice

Comment: You cannot open the html files saved in the assets folder by the another application.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open the html files saved in the assets folder by the another application.The asset directory is completely for your own app. No other app can access it.
However you can open it in your own WebView easily.
Another long approach can be reading and saving the data from the asset folder to the sdcard and the opening by the another programs.

**Edit:**
You can use the following code to display the html contents in webview

```
WebView webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wvOP);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/about_trt.html");
```

Ensure you have enabled hardware acceleration if you are using the flash contents-

```
<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
```

Comment: Thank
My problem is that I want to display an HTML file. But WebView error.

Comment: Thank My problem is that I want to display an HTML5 file. But WebView error

Comment: I have used your code, but unfortunately not the full page to load.
(A flash file converted to HTML5)